# Does anyone know this card game

Tags: identify-this-game

I like to know the name of a card game. It has a pack of cards and someone nominates someone to do an action on that card, e.g.:

- "crawl on your hands and knees like a cat and meow at each person"
- "go around each person and kiss them on the nose"
- "walk up and down in a red dress like your on a catwalk"

Unfortunately I have no clue as to when and where the game was produced. This game is a family game, no rude ones in there as far as I can remember. I've looked at Cranium, but that's not it.

I don't have any real pictures of the game, other than a very low-resolution image I pulled out from another photo I have, showing a back card with an orange or red border and white text:

[image: a very low-resolution blurry card]

I have been hunting high and low for it and for the life of me I can't find it anywhere! Its silly little actions are hilarious.

Comment: There are countless "party" games like this. Some are child friendly and some are 18+. Do you have any clue on when the game is produced and where? That might narrow down the search a bit.

Comment: Can you provide some pictures of the game?

Answer (score 2):

Is it "[We Didn’t Playtest This At All](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/31016/we-didnt-playtest-all)"?
It has cards with really strange rules like you describe and there are indeed booster packs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be the Party Game Quelf.
https://boardgamegeek.com/image/162770/quelf
Has a photo of the cards that look close to what you are holding

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more childish, but [Cranium Game](https://www.walmart.com/ip/23001240?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&adid=22222222227023293659&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=40344671192&wl4=pla-78309348152&wl5=9032443&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=online&wl12=23001240&wl13=&veh=sem) is like that. $12 at Walmart. I've never heard of an adult version the way you described.

Comment: I dunno, Cranium has things you have to think about, things you can get right or wrong. The OP's sounds like silly suggestions for the dare half of truth or dare.